# Payara / Glassfish 5 - [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] The SSL certificate has expired - cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81

Tags: java, glassfish

Today noticed the error message below the logs of my Payara5 server and since Glassfish is so popular these days, I spent a bit of time to find out what to do.

```
[2024-01-31T16:44:11.325+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [WARNING] [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] [javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl] [tid: _ThreadID=18107 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(25)] [timeMillis: 1706719451325] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: OU=Trustis FPS Root CA, O=Trustis Limited, C=GB
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 24908633667180321967674873268814531635547921938344065146546904438489502673823487510936146573960061486273718694334781317348708908262947651303078579882700224692570831312368945979170373153648052597761950956395913615810736512525962630740585310636521594672085066580175665043758918430925599500808969653476864564698808991702431004110644739915567322643581281788777374680963817281333282843028696667329131753328247995199072853681672136148214770992098772732734082912115629981882473191620546572069699037050136366328673247895507219755706167110912566425482228784709797122932080366498493920541761658523188072646247208026589367964269
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Dec 23 12:14:06 UTC 2003,
               To: Sun Jan 21 11:36:54 UTC 2024]
  Issuer: OU=Trustis FPS Root CA, O=Trustis Limited, C=GB
  SerialNumber: [    1b1fadb6 20f924d3 366bf7c7 f18ca059]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BA FA 71 25 79 8B 57 41   25 21 86 0B 71 EB B2 64  ..q%y.WA%!..q..d
0010: 0E 8B 21 67                                        ..!g
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BA FA 71 25 79 8B 57 41   25 21 86 0B 71 EB B2 64  ..q%y.WA%!..q..d
0010: 0E 8B 21 67                                        ..!g
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 7E 58 FF FD 35 19 7D 9C   18 4F 9E B0 2B BC 8E 8C  .X..5....O..+...
0010: 14 FF 2C A0 DA 47 5B C3   EF 81 2D AF 05 EA 74 48  ..,..G[...-...tH
0020: 5B F3 3E 4E 07 C7 6D C5   B3 93 CF 22 35 5C B6 3F  [.>N..m...."5\.?
0030: 75 27 5F 09 96 CD A0 FE   BE 40 0C 5C 12 55 F8 93  u'_......@.\.U..
0040: 82 CA 29 E9 5E 3F 56 57   8B 38 36 F7 45 1A 4C 28  ..).^?VW.86.E.L(
0050: CD 9E 41 B8 ED 56 4C 84   A4 40 C8 B8 B0 A5 2B 69  ..A..VL..@....+i
0060: 70 04 6A C3 F8 D4 12 32   F9 0E C3 B1 DC 32 84 44  p.j....2.....2.D
0070: 2C 6F CB 46 0F EA 66 41   0F 4F F1 58 A5 A6 0D 0D  ,o.F..fA.O.X....
0080: 0F 61 DE A5 9E 5D 7D 65   A1 3C 17 E7 A8 55 4E EF  .a...].e.<...UN.
0090: A0 C7 ED C6 44 7F 54 F5   A3 E0 8F F0 7C 55 22 8F  ....D.T......U".
00A0: 29 B6 81 A3 E1 6D 4E 2C   1B 80 67 EC AD 20 9F 0C  )....mN,..g.. ..
00B0: 62 61 D5 97 FF 43 ED 2D   C1 DA 5D 29 2A 85 3F AC  ba...C.-..])*.?.
00C0: 65 EE 86 0F 05 8D 90 5F   DF EE 9F F4 BF EE 1D FB  e......_........
00D0: 98 E4 7F 90 2B 84 78 10   0E 6C 49 53 EF 15 5B 65  ....+.x..lIS..[e
00E0: 46 4A 5D AF BA FB 3A 72   1D CD F6 25 88 1E 97 CC  FJ]...:r...%....
00F0: 21 9C 29 01 0D 65 EB 57   D9 F3 57 96 BB 48 CD 81  !.)..e.W..W..H..

]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** I am creating this post to help those facing the same issue and hopefully they can avoid spending hours investigating how to solve the issue. Especially if they are facing it the first time.*

To fix it, you will need to remove the expired certificate from `cacerts.jks` located in your Payara/Glassfish domain config folder. In the below example Payara resides in `/opt/payara5` folder, so domain config folder is `/opt/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/`.

1. Take note of the expiry date from the error message: `Sun Jan 21 11:36:54 UTC 2024`
2. Take a backup of your `cacerts.jks`

```
cp cacerts.jks cacerts.jks_backup_20240131
```

3. Check the certificates in `cacerts.jks` (default password always: `changeit`), and try to find the certificate `Sun Jan 21 11:36:54 UTC 2024` expiry date, take note of the alias

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts.jks
*******************************************
Alias name: cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81
Creation date: Jan 23, 2018
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: OU=Trustis FPS Root CA, O=Trustis Limited, C=GB
Issuer: OU=Trustis FPS Root CA, O=Trustis Limited, C=GB
Serial number: 1b1fadb620f924d3366bf7c7f18ca059
Valid from: Tue Dec 23 12:14:06 UTC 2003 until: Sun Jan 21 11:36:54 UTC 2024
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 3B:C0:38:0B:33:C3:F6:A6:0C:86:15:22:93:D9:DF:F5:4B:81:C0:04
     SHA256: C1:B4:82:99:AB:A5:20:8F:E9:63:0A:CE:55:CA:68:A0:3E:DA:5A:51:9C:88:02:A0:D3:A6:73:BE:8F:8E:55:7D
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
*******************************************
```

4. Now remove the expired certificate:

```
keytool -delete -keystore cacerts.jks -alias cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81 -v
Enter keystore password:
[Storing cacerts.jks]
```

5. Check the result:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts.jks -alias cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81 -v
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81> does not exist
java.lang.Exception: Alias <cert_81_trustis_fps_root_ca81> does not exist
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintEntry(Main.java:1895)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1143)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:378)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:371)
```

6. Restart your domain:

```
cd /opt/payara5/glassfish/bin
./asadmin restart-domain domain1
```

**References:**

- [[Wayback Machine] "SEC5054: Certificate has expired" error message in the GlassFish Application Server log](https://web.archive.org/web/20140713065413/https://blogs.oracle.com/ramkri/entry/sec5054_certificate_has_expired_error)
- [[Stack Overflow] "Certificate has expired" in log by starting Glassfish 3.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248020/certificate-has-expired-in-log-by-starting-glassfish-3-1-2)